# pgfplot does not allow [] brackets in axis title

Tags: pgfplots, brackets

In my pgfplot I labled the x and y axis `xlabel=age (weeks)` and `label=weight (g)`. But instead of the `()` brackets I would like to have **week** and **g** in `[]` brackets.

But when I change it the y label disappears and the the x axis title is only half drawn (see pic).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{
    pgfplots.dateplot,
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{filecontents}{maleWT.csv}
    age, weight
    3,  6
    4,  12
    5,  15
    6,  18
    7,  20
    8,  22
    9,  23
    10, 24
    11, 25
    12, 26
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    table/col sep=comma,
                    xtick=data,
                    title=\textbf{male weight},
                    grid=major,
                    grid style={dashed,gray!30},
                    xlabel=age [weeks],
                    ylabel=weight [g],
                    ymin = 0,
                    legend entries={WT,KO,HZ},
                    legend style={
                        at={(0.9,0.25)},
                        anchor=east}
                    ]
                    \addplot[black, mark=o]  table[x=age,y=weight] {maleWT.csv};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Has anyone a clue why it does not let me put `[]` brackets in the axis title but `()` brackets and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: @ Campa I thought I tried this. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's the common problem of using square brackets in optional parameters: the parser considers the `]` after "weeks" as the one closing the optional parameter of the `axis` environment.